# Html Div Alignment Issues

Tags: html

I am working on a blog for a project, and I have a certain layout planned, with a top header, nav to the left, 2 sections in the middle (One is the article, the other a comments section.), and a side bar (aside) to the right. The only problem with this is that the side bar's top margin aligns with the lower comments section, rather than the top article's section. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/randomname14/nvu4qhcp/5/, also the full screen result (http://jsfiddle.net/randomname14/nvu4qhcp/5/embedded/result/)

And Here's the Code (sorry about it being the whole body, but I am unsure of what could be causing the problem, so I left in most parts)

```
<body>


<header>

<a href="my page.html" style="font-size:500%; text-decoration: none;"> <span style="color: #FFFFFF">tech</span><span style="color: #DB4105;">news</span><span style="color: #FFFFFF">daily</span> </a>

</header>

<nav>
<hr/>
<b><a href="my page.html" style="color: #FFFFFF;">Home</a><br>
<hr>
Hardware<br>
<hr/>
Software<br>
<hr/>
Builds<br>
<hr/>
Games<br>
<hr/>
Pereipherals<br>
<hr/>
Other Stuff<br>
<hr/>
FAQ<br>
<hr/>
Contact Me<br>
<hr/>
</nav>

<section>

<h1 style="font-size: 200%"> Article Title </h1>

<img src="amd-radeon-logo.jpg" width="1095" border="3px">
Article
</p>

</section>

<section>

<textarea rows="10" cols="101" placeholder="Like this article if you liked it, dislike it if you disliked it, or leave a comment down below if your thoughts are more complicated than this."></textarea>

</section>

<aside style=" color: #FFFFFF;">

<hr/>
<hr/>
<b>
<a href="http://www.reddit.com" style="text-decoration:none">
<img src="Ad.png" width="416" border="3px">
</a>
<p style=" color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 125%"><b> Buy a Shirt today! </b></p>
<hr/>
<p style=" color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 125%"><b> Older Articles </b></p>
<img src="390.jpg" width="416" border="3px">
<p style=" color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 70%"><b> AMD R9 300 Series GPU Leaked in Photos with R9 295X2 Cooler Design. </b> </p>
<img src="INTEL.jpg" width="416" border="3px">
<p style=" color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 70%"><b> 14nm Intel Core M Broadwell-Y Laptops Coming Soon. </b></p>
<img src="W10.png" width="416" border="3px">
<p style=" color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 70%"><b> Microsoft Unveils the Next Version of Windows. Uh, I Think They Forgot a Number... </b></p>
<img src="Ubisoft.jpg" width="416" border="3px">
<p style=" color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 70%"><b> Ubisoft Blames OEMs for AC: Unity Performance Issues, <i>Really?</i> </b></p>
<img src="780TI.jpg" width="416" border="3px">
<p style=" color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 70%"><b> GeForce GTX 700 Series Price Drops After 900 Series Unveiling </b></p>
<img src="GEFORCE.png" width="416" border="3px">
<p style=" color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 70%"><b> Nvidia Unveils 2nd Generation Maxwell GPUs, The GTX 900 Series. </b></p>
<hr/>
Social:<br>
<br>
<img src="TWITTER.png" width="30">
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" style="color : white">Twitter</a>
<br>
<img src="FACEBOOK.png" width="30">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" style="color : white">Facebook</a>
<br>
<img src="YOUTUBE.png" width="30">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com" style="color : white">YouTube</a>
<hr/>
Top Channels:<br>
<br>
<img src="LINUS.jpg" width="30">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/linustechtips/videos" style="color : white;">Linus</a>
<br>
<img src="TEK.jpg" width="30">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/razethew0rld/videos" style="color : white;">Logan</a>
<br>
<hr/>
PC Builder Resources:
<br>
<br>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.intel,com" style="color : white;">Intel</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.amd.com" style="color : white;">AMD</a></li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<hr/>
</b>
</aside>

<footer> © Name, 2000-2014, all rights reserved. </footer>
```

Comment: You should use http://validator.w3.org/ , your HTML contains a lot of errors (unterminated tags (img, a, li...), b containing block elements ...)

Comment: I tried using html tidy to clean it up, and it tested it, it entirely messed up the layout. Also about the errors, I am fairly new to html, I started about 3-4 months ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the 'articles' (the `section` elements) inside of a parent container.

HTML:

```
<div class="main-content">
    <section>
        <h1 ... content of section 1 ... </p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <textarea ... content of section 2 ... </textarea>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-content {
    width:1100px;
    float: left;
}
section {
    width:1100px;
    /*float: left; **can remove float** */
    padding:10px;
    ...
}
```

[**DEMO** (with reduced width for demonstration purposes)](http://jsfiddle.net/nvu4qhcp/6/)